# how to store used image into one drawable folder to decrease memory in android application

Tags: android, drawable

I am developing an application where i need to use 30 MB of data in image form.
But i have to store it twice in drawable and drawable-v24 folder to use images, this fact consuming 60 MB of my apk file. Any solution to over cum this issue?

Comment: Why don't you download them to local storage or cache "depending on your case" when your app is launched for the first time "or when needed" instead of adding them to the apk?

Comment: can you please describe it how can i do this?

Comment: You can start by searching for how to download files to internal storage or cache, then check if the files exists before using them as the user can delete the app storage.